# Testing $state.go giving error in Angular JS spec

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine

I am having below Controller in Angular JS

```
describe('Controller: homeCtrl', function () {
  beforeEach(module('incident'));
  var homeCtrl, $state;

  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, _$state_) {
      $state = _$state_;
      homeCtrl = $controller('homeCtrl', {$state: $state});
  }));

  it('to be defined', function () {
    expect( homeCtrl).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('to be defined state', inject(function ($state) {
      $state.expectTransitionTo('incidents');
  }));
});
```

While writing spec for $state.go like below, it is giving error as per attached image:

```
describe('Controller: homeCtrl', function () {
  beforeEach(module('incident'));
  var homeCtrl, $state;

  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, _$state_) {
      $state = _$state_;
      homeCtrl = $controller('homeCtrl', {$state: $state});
  }));

  it('to be defined state', inject(function ($state) {
      $state.expectTransitionTo('incidents');
  }));

});
```

[image]

Any suggestion will be helpful or any sample code which shows how can i test this $state.go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to spy on state to make transition between states.here is the code

```
describe('Controller: homeCtrl', function () {
  beforeEach(module('incident'));
  var homeCtrl, $state;

  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, _$state_) {
      $state = _$state_;
       spyOn('$state','go'); spyOn($state, 'go');
       // or
       spyOn($state, 'go').andCallFake(function(state, params) {
        // This replaces the 'go' functionality for the duration of your test
       });
      homeCtrl = $controller('homeCtrl', {$state: $state});
  }));

  it('to be defined state', inject(function ($state) {
      $state.expectTransitionTo('incidents');
  }));

});
```

Answer (score 0):

`expectTransitionTo` is not a function that ships with ui-router innately. I assume you saw it from [this](https://gist.github.com/wilsonwc/8358542) gist, in which case, you need to use that gist and also set up the `stateMock` module.